# How can I get the count of specific item in multidimensional array swift

Tags: ios, swift, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get the count of specific item when its value is set to true. Is my implementation right. I am getting error index out of range when I try to populate the the win. count value in a table view.

```
struct Game {
    var rivalGoal: String?
    var userGoal: String
    var win: Bool
}
```

---

```
var games: [Game?] = []
var weekLeagueObject: [[Game?]] = []
```

The way I did it is :

```
func winCountMethod (from games: [[Game?]], index: Int) -> Int {
    let win = games.filter({$0[index]?.win == true})
    return win.count
}
```

Comment: `weekLeagueObject` is not really an object, because arrays are value types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do it:

```
func winCountMethod (from games: [[Game?]], index: Int) -> Int {
    return games[index].compactMap { $0?.win }.filter { $0 }.count
}
```

Comment: @Vangola this will unnecessarily iterate the whole array twice. Your attempt was really close and it is better than this answer if you succeeded `games[index].filter({$0?.win == true}).count` . The other answer that uses reduce is much better

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array method `reduce()` for that:

```
func getNumberOfWonGame() -> Int {
    games.reduce(0) { (result, game) in
        game.isWin ? result + 1 : result
    }
}

func getNumberOfWonGameShortened() -> Int {
    games.reduce(0) { $1.isWin ? $0 + 1 : $0 }
}
```

For your concrete example it might be :

```
func winCountMethod(from games: [[Game?]], index: Int) -> Int {
    games[index].reduce(0) { (result, game) in
        guard let game = game, !game.win else { return result }
        return result + 1
    }
}
```

Comment: `games[index].reduce(0) { $0 + ($1?.win == true ? 1 : 0) }`

Comment: I think the other overload of reduce, with `if game?.win == true { result += 1 }`, is better for this.

Answer (score 0):

Given `index` as some `Int`, you can use extensions to write it like this:

```swift
try weekLeagueObject.getElement(index: index).getCount(\.win)
```

```swift
public extension Collection {
  /// - Returns: same as subscript, if index is in bounds
  /// - Throws: CollectionIndexingError
  func getElement(index: Index) throws -> Element {
    guard indices.contains(index)
    else { throw CollectionIndexingError() }

    return self[index]
  }
}

public struct CollectionIndexingError: Error { }

public extension Sequence {
  func getCount<Wrapped>(
    _ getIsIncluded: (Wrapped) throws -> Bool
  ) rethrows -> Int?
  where Element == Wrapped? {
    try filter { try $0.map(getIsIncluded) == true }
      .count
  }
}
```